# javascript class id counting up on object creation

Tags: javascript

Currently the result of this is 2 and 2 because both objects are acessing the same global var. but how can i have an id that counts upwards on object creation so that i have id of 1 and 2 and so on?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id =0;
    class theObject{
        constructor(){
            this.id=id++;
        }
        writeOutput(){
            console.log("write output");
            $('<span>').appendTo('#output').html("id:"+id);

        }
    }

    var theObject1 = new theObject();
    var theObject2 = new theObject();

    $(document).ready(function(){

        theObject1.writeOutput();
        theObject2.writeOutput();
    })


    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="output"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the global (`id`) in `writeOutput`. Instead, you want the instance property (`this.id`):

```
$('<span>').appendTo('#output').html("id:" + this.id);
// ------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

```js
var id =0;
class theObject{
    constructor(){
        this.id=id++;
    }
    writeOutput(){
        console.log("write output");
        $('<span>').appendTo('#output').html("id:" + this.id);

    }
}

var theObject1 = new theObject();
var theObject2 = new theObject();

$(document).ready(function(){

    theObject1.writeOutput();
    theObject2.writeOutput();
})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Separately, for what it's worth, I wouldn't use a global. I'd use something private to the class, like this:

```js
const theObject = (() => {
  var id = 0;
  return class theObject{
      constructor(){
          this.id=id++;
      }
      writeOutput(){
          console.log("write output");
          $('<span>').appendTo('#output').html("id:" + this.id);

      }
  };
})();
console.log(typeof id); // "undefined", `id` isn't exposed here

var theObject1 = new theObject();
var theObject2 = new theObject();

$(document).ready(function(){
    theObject1.writeOutput();
    theObject2.writeOutput();
})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript code is that constructor functions are named with an initial capital letter, so `TheObject` rather than `theObject`.

Comment: Upvoting for leading away from the use of globals. Good answer, @T.J.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing class variables with global variables. Note that in the constructor you set the value of `this.id`, but in writeOutput() you display the value of `id`, not `this.id`. `id` is your global variable, not a part of your class. It is meant to track the count, but is not the stored value for each instance of the class.

To achieve what you're going for, your write output method should look like the following:

```
writeOutput()
{
    console.log("write output");
    $('<span>').appendTo('#output').html("id:"+this.id);
}
```